# How could I change time for Net::ReadTimeout globally

Tags: ruby

There are lots of network read action in my application.

I want to change the timeout threadshould in 5 seconds

However, even I put this code in my application ,

The timeout still stays in 60 seconds

```
require 'net/http'
module Net
  class HTTP < Protocol
    alias_method :old_initialize, :initialize

    def initialize(address, port = nil, open_timeout: 5)
      old_initialize(address, port)
      self.open_timeout = open_timeout
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using rails framework then put above code in config/initializers folder may be it works